# Updating Description and Custom Attributes on a Docs File

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-data-management

Is it possible to update the `Description` and/or a custom created attribute on a Docs file via the API?

The following two API calls suggest that an update can be made at either the item/file level or the version level but which one should be used and how would you access a custom created attribute?

- https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-items-item_id-PATCH/
- https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-versions-version_id-PATCH/

The sample call provided shows renaming a file. Presumably `Description` and any custom attribute (e.g. `My New Attribute`) would be access using `description` and `my new attribute`, respectively as the "id" to be updated(?)

I have the upload of a file already working and showing in Docs but after the upload is complete I need to push metadata into it and the API isn't clear on how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the Attributes (from BIM 360 Docs) are not yet exposed via Data Management API. We're investigating this and this is our tracking number: `FDM-1963`